# list dependencies of a pre-built package of ros?

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the full desktop version of ROS kinetic instead of building it from the source files. I would like to know the list  of dependencies for a pre-built package in ROS ( for ex, turtlesim ). Is there a command that can list all the dependencies of a pre-built package. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254910/list-dependencies-of-a-pre-built-package-of-ros-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

found it. rospack depends does the job!

---

Originally posted by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) with karma: 231 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0